# Some Attributes not showing in Android Studio inside the Linear Layout

Tags: java, android

Some Attributes are now showing in Andoid Studio. I also rebuid project, cleared cache, resync project and also reinstalled everything but still it is not working.enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvrD5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried closing and re-opening android studio? It seems more like a system error than on you. Hope this helps!